# Python: cannot import from PyQt5.QtCore (attempting example script)

Tags: python, pyqt4, importerror, pyqt5, qtcore

I'm introducing myself to PyQt5 through one of its included examples. On this windows 7 machine, I have installed Python 3.4 x64, and PyQt5 using its binary provided on riverbankcomputiong.com. The documentation says that the binary already includes everything necessary to run. I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed that i can safely skip the "configure" and "build" steps at Riverbank's installation guide, since the guide only talks about .zip, .tar, etc. files.

I used the tutorial located here:

```
http://www.pythonschool.net/pyqt/introduction-to-pyqt/
```

Which also says "just run the binary to install pyqt4 there is no step three."

When i attempt to run any tutorial containing reference to PyQt4 or PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
```

I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

But when i enter the following:

```
import PyQt5
```

The interpreter seems to be okay with it -- no errors.

I can't help but think I've done something wrong installation, because even when I run the examples **included** with PyQt4/PyQt5, i get importerrors. It seems as though QtCore doesn't even exist in relation to PyQt4 or PyQt5. What's going on here?

Comment: It sounds like you might need to update your PATH environment variable to include the location where the library is installed (i.e. directory location where the DLLs are)

Comment: Using windows command prompt and entering:
'echo %PATH%' 
yeilds lots and lots of paths to various folders. Two of which are two the PyQt5 folder (C:\Python34\Lib\Site-packages\PyQt5), and the Python34 folder (C:\Python34)
Are those two correct?

Comment: Seems likely to be ok. Assuming it is, keep in mind PyQt5 is a *binding* to Qt. You must still install the Qt Framework for the bindings to work. If this works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few possibilities:

- You might need to update your PATH environment variable to include the location where the library is installed (i.e. directory location where the DLLs are)
- Take note of where you're launching the interpreter or scripts from as their current path may not necessarily include what you expect.

You can check this with:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)
```

- Make sure the installation process was truly successful (i.e. zero errors) and that you downloaded the correct binary package for your PC's architecture.

I ran into a similar issue with PySide where `import PySide` would work but `import PySide.QtCore` would fail.

I'd expect the code to work after verifying those things:

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import *
>>>
```

If it doesn't, update the question with additional details like things you checked, their values, error messages, etc.